# javascript constructor + node js createServer

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to wrap node js server in JS object, 
In order to do that, I wrote this constructor:

```
function staticServerObj (rootFolder) {
    this.rootFolder = rootFolder;
    this.port = null;
    this.isStarted = false;
    this.startedData = null;
    this.numOfCurrentRequests = 0;
    this.numOfAllRequests = 0;
    this.numOfSuccesfulRequest = 0;

    this.serverObj = net.createServer(function (socket) {
        handleNewConnection(this, socket);
    });
};
```

The problem is, in handleNewConnection function, Im trying to use my staticServerObj vars (like: staticServerObj.port) and it's undefined, 
Furthermore, when I try to log the server object in that way:

```
function handleNewConnection(server, socket) {
    console.log(server);
}
```

Im getting this result:

```
{ domain: null,
  _events: { connection: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  _connections: 1,
  connections: [Getter/Setter],
  _handle: 
   { fd: 12,
     writeQueueSize: 0,
     onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
     owner: [Circular] },
  _usingSlaves: false,
  _slaves: [],
  allowHalfOpen: false,
  _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:1234' }
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have a scoping problem. The `this` inside your `createServer()` does not point to the server object anymore. To solve this either save a reference to the `staticServerObj` like this:

```
function staticServerObj (rootFolder) {
    this.rootFolder = rootFolder;
    this.port = null;
    this.isStarted = false;
    this.startedData = null;
    this.numOfCurrentRequests = 0;
    this.numOfAllRequests = 0;
    this.numOfSuccesfulRequest = 0;

    var that = this;

    this.serverObj = net.createServer(function (socket) {
        handleNewConnection(that, socket);
    });
};
```

or use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and have access to the `this` reference inside your function:

```
function staticServerObj (rootFolder) {
    this.rootFolder = rootFolder;
    this.port = null;
    this.isStarted = false;
    this.startedData = null;
    this.numOfCurrentRequests = 0;
    this.numOfAllRequests = 0;
    this.numOfSuccesfulRequest = 0;

    var that = this;

    this.serverObj = net.createServer( handleNewConnection.bind( this ) );
};

function handleNewConnection(socket) {
   // your former server variable can now be accessed using `this`
    console.log( this );
}
```